# apache2 Use of undefined constant PASSWORD_ARGON2I on ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2

I'm struggeling to setup my source on apache2.
I've manually installed PHP 7.2.9 With the Aragon2I Libaries.
But i'm still getting the error 
PASSWORD_ARGON2I - assumed 'PASSWORD_ARGON2I'

 What can i do to resolve this issue?

Comment: It works perfectly fine on my local XAMPP Webserver. This is really confusing

Comment: It also seems to work on the command line of my webserver, But it doesn't do anything in apache2

Comment: Did you check the output from `phpinfo()`

Comment: Hmm, Seems like i can't find anything about aragon2i there either.

Comment: Did you install from packages, or compile PHP yourself

Comment: Compiled it myself

Comment: Did you `http://php.net/manual/en/password.installation.php`

Comment: yes, it's working on command line. but not the webserver

Comment: Been a while since I ubuntu'd but the PHP exe for CLI and the one used on the web server are different. Did you just compile CLI? Or did you forget the option when compiling PHP for web server